# Is there a way to write on xml files with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms, xml-serialization

I am working on a simple app that has saving/retrieving object data functionality.

I did manage to get data from a pre-filled xml file and display it as list in the app (see the following code).

```
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;


        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Fetch.Pieces.xml");
             ObservableCollection<Piece> ListPieces;

             using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
             {
                 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Piece>));
                 ListPieces = (ObservableCollection<Piece>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
             }
```

However, i can't seem to find some documentation for the writing process, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: You just serialize your data and write it.  The catch is that if your are using a PCL most profiles don't support direct file I/O.  You can either use a DependencyService to access the platform file I/O, or use a package like PCLStorage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasn't notified. I ended up using the package PCLStorage and made it work, but I wasn't able to write on the file directly with a "StreamMwriter"